# What is a barracks' sight range?

Tags: starcraft-2

What is a barracks' sight range?

Can't find this information...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the Starcraft 2 Editor, the Barracks has a sight range of 9.
[image]

Comment: Does it have the same sight range while flying?

Comment: sight range is not affected by air-level of unit. Except for ramps and walls of course